# && и || с разными типами данных

Tags: javascript

Я только начал изучать JavaScript и прорешивал задачки.

И начали попадаться такие задания как:
•   Чему равно 2 && 1 && null && 0 && undefined ?
•   Чему равно 0 || "" || 2 || undefined || true || falsе ?

Как можно сравнивать разные типы данных?

Comment: Вроде в любом учебнике рассказывают про && и ||, не?

Comment: Для удобства использования, в JS все типы данных приводятся к логическому типу

Answer (score -2, accepted):

`&&` и `||` это операции **логического** И и ИЛИ. На вход они принимают два логических операнда и возвращает результат логического типа

В JavaScript нет строгой типизации, поэтому операнды преобразовываются к тому типу, который требуется в выражении.

Т.е. в вашем случае все операнды преобразуются в логический тип.

Алгоритм преобразования такой:

```
Значение         | Преобразуется в...
-----------------|--------------------
undefined, null  | false
Числа            | Все true, кроме 0, NaN -- false.
Строки           | Все true, кроме пустой строки "" -- false
Объекты          | Всегда true
```

Comment: _На вход они принимают два логических операнда и возвращает результат логического типа_ - для яваскрипта это утверждение неверно.

Answer (score 11):

Если обратиться к [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-binary-logical-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

```
LogicalANDExpression : LogicalANDExpression && BitwiseORExpression
1. Пусть lref результат вычисления LogicalANDExpression.
2. Пусть lval будет результатом GetValue(lref).
3. Пусть lbool результат ToBoolean(lval).
4. Если lbool - false, вернуть lval.
5. Пусть rref это результат вычисления BitwiseORExpression.
6. Вернуть GetValue(rref).
```

В случае `&&` левый операнд приводится к `bool` и если значение `false` возвращается сам операнд. В противном случае возвращается правый операнд.

```
LogicalORExpression : LogicalORExpression || LogicalANDExpression
1. Пусть lref результат вычисления LogicalORExpression.
2. Пусть lval будет результатом GetValue(lref).
3. Пусть lbool результат ToBoolean(lval).
4. Если lbool - true, вернуть lval.
5. Пусть rref это результат вычисления LogicalANDExpression.
6. Вернуть GetValue(rref).
```

В случае `||` левый операнд приводится к `bool` и если значение `true` возвращается сам операнд. В противном случае возвращается правый операнд.

Comment: Для полноты надо бы добавить ответы на вопросы в посте.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, собственно ответ как раз и есть о том как работают логические операторы и почему такие выражения как в вопросе допустимы

Answer (score 5):

В javascript такие вопросы решаются очень просто: [приведением типов](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion) ( в данном случае будет приводится к булевому типу )

***Зачем это нужно?***

В javascript `&&` и `||` ленивые операторы, то есть они не всегда будут высчитывать все значения. Например: если мы используем `&&`, то `true` будет только в том случае, если обе переменные `true`

```
true && false // false
false && false // false
true && true // true
false && true // false
```

В последнем примере нам даже не обязательно высчитывать значение второй переменной, так как первая `false`, то мы уже точно знаем, что результат тоже будет `false`. Этим можно воспользоваться в некоторых ситуациях

```
const element = document.getElementById('id'); // какой-то элемент

//теперь представим, что нам нужно что-то сделать с этим элементом
// в случае если он есть на странице
// можно сделать так
if(element) {
    someFn(element);
}

// а можно короче воспользовавшись ленивостью оператора &&
element && someFn(element); // someFn вызовется только если element true
```

В доказательство, что движок даже не смотрит изначально за `&&` в том, что

```
false && arueybgqnreugnqgr(); // все ок
```

То же самое с `||`, только его используют для других целей:

```
const fn = param => {
    return param || 42 // по сути так мы устанавливаем значение по умолчанию
}

fn(10); // 10
fn(); // 42
fn(0); // тоже 42, потому что !!0 === false
```

Пустая строка, `0`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `null`  (кажется, ничего не забыл ) - приводятся к `false`. Остальное к `true`, причем:

```
!![]; // true
!!({}); // true
```

Comment: мне нравитсья ваши ответы я много чего учусь и узнаю у вас спасибо что помогаете людям.