# Рефакторинг проверки

Tags: javascript

Как можно лучше привести в порядок проверку в `myFunc`. Хотел использовать `typeof obj.files === 'obj'` но может зайти `null` и тогда покрешится все.

```js
var obj1 = {
  files: null
}
var obj2 = {
  files: {
    video: 'video_link'
  }
}
var obj3 = {
  files: {
    file: 'link_to_download'
  }
}
var obj4 = {}

function myFunc(obj) {
  return obj.files ? obj.files !== null ? obj.files.video ?
    obj.files.video : obj.files.file ?
    obj.files.file : null : null : null
}

console.log(myFunc(obj1))
console.log(myFunc(obj2))
console.log(myFunc(obj3))
console.log(myFunc(obj4))
```

Comment: после `obj.files` нет нужды проверять `obj.files !== null`

Comment: Проверка на `obj.files !== null` бессмысленна. Она находится в ветке, где `!!obj.files == true`, a `!!null == false`. Но это просто беглый взгляд

Comment: в принципе можно проверку заменить на следующее: `obj.files && (obj.files.video || obj.files.file)`

Comment: @Grundy Как в этом примере понять `obj.files && (obj.files.video || obj.files.file)` это видео или файл?

Comment: @Puvvl, а зачем тебе это понимать? :-) возвращается первый не false поле из `video` или `file`, судя по текущему коду это именно то, что ты сейчас и делаешь

Comment: @Puvvl, возможно ты не понял что именно я предложил заменить: тело функции теперь должно стать таким `return obj.files && (obj.files.video || obj.files.file)`. Без тернарных операторов

Comment: @Grundy, понял, отлично :) Спасибо, можете вставить в ответ и я его приму :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для упрощения условия сначала необходимо определить, что именно в нем проверяется и что возвращается:

```
return obj.files ? obj.files !== null ? obj.files.video ?
    obj.files.video : obj.files.file ?
    obj.files.file : null : null : null
```

Для этого можно переписать все с помощью `if`

```
if(obj.files){
    if(obj.files != null){
        if(obj.files.video){
            return obj.files.video;
        }else if (obj.files.file){
            return obj.files.file;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}else{
    return null;
}
```

Далее можно рассматривать сами условия.

Проверка на существование свойства `obj.files` и сравнение этого свойства с `null` взаимозаменяемы, и фактически первые два условия проверяют одно и то же, поэтому одно можно убрать, получим следующее

```
if(obj.files){
    if(obj.files.video){
        return obj.files.video;
    }else if (obj.files.file){
        return obj.files.file;
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}else{
    return null;
}
```

Далее можно убрать строки `return null`, так как их отсутствие эквивалентно наличию `return undefined`, что при нестрогой проверке результата эквивалентно возвращению `null`

```
if(obj.files){
    if(obj.files.video){
        return obj.files.video;
    }else if (obj.files.file){
        return obj.files.file;
    }
}
```

Так как в условиях проверяется конкретное поле и в случае успеха оно же возвращается можно заменить `if`, на логические операторы:

1. вложенные `if` меняются на `&&` с внешним условием
2. `if .. else` меняется на `||`

Получаем следующее

```
return obj.files && (obj.files.video || obj.files.file)
```

<sub>Подробнее про работу логических операторов можно посмотреть в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/866559/186999)</sub>