# Условные операторы в javascript

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JS, наткнулся в книге на такой код:

```
var handlers = this._eventHandlers && this._eventHandlers[eventName];
if(!handlers) return;
```

Я думал что объявление нескольких переменных в js делается просто через запятую, а здесь что имеется ввиду? 
И во второй строчке, если я правильно понял имеется ввиду: `if (handlers = false)`, `return false`. Так? Или что-то другое подразумевается? Спасибо.

Comment: Именно это имеется в виду

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц Спасибо, а про первую строчку можете еще разъяснить?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [&& и || с разными типами данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/866554/186999)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Я думал что объявление нескольких переменных в js делается просто через запятую

делается, но у вас здесь определена только одна переменная - `handlers`. Ее значение определяется логическим выражением (логическое И), которое в свою очередь проверяет наличие объекта `_eventHandlers` и его свойства с именем `eventName`. Если оба не пусты и существуют получим результат `true`.

> если я правильно понял имеется ввиду:

```
if (handlers = false),
```

в таком виде у вас `handlers` примет значение `false`. Оператор сравненеия это двойное равенство `==`.

```
return false
```

не додумываете то, чего нет. Не было там `false`, вернется значение `undefined`.

Comment: про первую строчку понял. Спасибо. А про вторую можете написать просто словами без примеров, как с первой строкой что имеется ввиду здесь `if(!handlers) return`

Comment: А ведь в `handlers` будет храниться не `true`, а `this._eventHandlers[eventName]`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko да, вы правы.

Comment: @teran можете теперь мне объяснить?:)

Comment: @AsasSas так работает оператор в JS. В прочих языках обычно такая конструкция всегда приводит к булевому результату, но в JS возвращается последний операнд, если выражение вычислено как true. Подробнее про логические операторы в JS с примерами можете глянуть [по этой ссылке](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)

Comment: @teran я про 2 строчку, если можно)

Comment: а что там объяснять? если `handlers`  в предыдущей строке было вычислено как `false`, то выходим. Т.е. `!false` нам дает `true` и выполнение `if`-а

Answer (score 0):

Первая строка толкуется так
Переменной присваивается true, если все условия соблюдаются и false если хоть одно условие не соблюдается и получаем

```
var s = true && false // s = false
var s = true && true // s = true
```

Comment: а почему в первой строчке получается `false`? То есть почему он выигрывает

Comment: @AsasSas очевидно потому, что это логическое `И`, оба операнда должны быть истинны.  Если было бы `Или` было бы `true`.

Comment: Логическое и получает t только если оба t, в остальных случаях он f