# Есть ли короткая запись для такой конструкции?

Tags: javascript

Вот для такого кода:

```
const ob = { a: {b: 2}};
const c = ob && ob.a && ob.a.b;
```

есть какой-то синтаксический сахар для второй строки?

Например, что-то похожее на это:

```
const c = ob?.a?.b;
```

Comment: в [спецификации](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/#sec-optional-chains) уже есть определение, чтобы можно было делать `const c = ob?.a?.b;`, но на сколько это уже поддерживается браузерами [не очень понятно](https://caniuse.com/?search=optional%20chaining)

Comment: Отлично. Даже синтаксис угадал. Через Бабель, главное работает. Спасибо.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что эквивалентный синтаксис `const c = ob && ob.a && ob.a.b;` будет: `const c = undefined !== ob?.a?.b;`.

Comment: @pasx, не будет

Comment: @Grundy думаю, что `const c = ob && ob.a && ob.a.b;` и `const c = undefined !== ob?.a?.b;` проверяют все термины в выражении и возвращает true или false. Но `const c = ob?.a?.b;` возвращает значение `ob.a.b`. Кстати, можно было бы записать как `const c = !!ob?.a?.b;`

Comment: @pasx, неправильно думаешь, логические операторы в js [возвращают один из операндов, а не логическое значение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/866559/186999).

Comment: @Grundy Вы правы. && оператор возвращает операнд.

Comment: @Grunby кстати, const c = ob?.['a']?.b - тоже работает. Вдруг кому-то будет полезно

Answer (score 1):

Такой синтаксис уже ввели, и назвали [`optional chaining`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/#sec-optional-chains)

Варианты использования

```
const c = ob?.a?.b;
const c = ob?.['a']?.['b'];

const c = ob?.().a?.().b; // в случае вызова функции
```

поддерживается в [большинстве реализаций](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-optional_chaining_operator_(?.)), кроме IE и EDGE на старом движке, а также nodejs < 14 версии

Comment: а с TS или каким-нибудь Babel так везде (при соответствующих телодвижениях, конечно же) вот [пример](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGMC8MDeMCGAuN8cCYBfQgbgChRJZhk54B+AOgyfnKA) во что TS компилирует

Comment: @qwabra, не понял комментарий

Comment: Grundy, "поддерживается в большинстве реализаций, кроме" - возьмём __pipeline operator__ для примера, он ещё в стадии 3, но использовать его можно уже давно с помощью [плагина для babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator) есть такая штука как полифилы, вот что я хотел сказать - не нужно зацикливаться на поддержке браузерами, хотя и забывать конечно же не стоит : )

Comment: @qwabra, что за pipeline operator?