# Как работают операторы присваивания логического И (&&=) и ИЛИ (||=)?

Tags: javascript

на сайте javaScript. ru ( онлайн учебник по js) В теме "логические операторы" есть задача:

```
let value = NaN;

value &&= 10;
value ||= 20;
value &&= 30;
value ||= 40;

alert(value);
```

не понимаю почему ответ именно "30"
в пояснении написано:

```
value &&= 30
value=20
```

20 конвертируется в логическое значение true
value истинно, поэтому присваивание срабатывает

почему `value=20`,
если в других строчках, например `value &&= 10`
value не равно 10, а NaN(

объясните, пожалуйста, я не могу понять

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: _"почему value=20, если в других строчках, например "value &&= 10" value не равно 10, а NaN"_ -- потому что оператор `&&` возвращает первое ложное значение, но присваивание не происходит, так как `&&=` присваивает новое значение только если левая часть (до `&&=`) истинна, а в случае с `value &&= 10;` она `NaN`.

Comment: Grundy, это не дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/866554/507426, этот вопрос - про побитовые логические операторы И/ИЛИ, а тот - про условные операторы вроде or/and в питоне. Они просто пишутся похоже.

Answer (score 3):

[Оператор логического И присваивания `&&=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND_assignment) вычисляет только правый операнд и присваивает значение левому, если левый операнд является истинным ([truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)). Но `NaN` - это [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) значение, т.е. если привести его к `Boolean`, то результат будет `fasle`, поэтому в выражение `value &&= 10;` присваивание не происходит и остается значение `NaN`.

[Логический оператор ИЛИ присваивание `||=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment) вычисляет только правый операнд и присваивает значение левому, если левый операнд является ложным ([falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)). В следующем выражение `value ||= 20;` в `value` всё ещё `NaN` - ложный, поэтому присваивание происходит, теперь `value` хранит `20`.